# FastApi как обработать HTTPException?

Tags: python, fastapi

Есть обработка роута

```py
@router.post('/api/fs/create-new-folder', tags=['File system'])
def handle_create_new_folder(request: CreateNewFolderReqModel, user_id=Depends(auth)):

  try:
    FsEntityController.create_entity(request.fs_entity, request.file_field, user_id)
    return {'result': 'success'}

  except HTTPException as exc:
    return JSONResponse(
      status_code=exc.status_code,
      content={'error': exc.detail}
    )
  except Exception as exc:
    return JSONResponse(
      status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      content={'error': 'Internal server error'}
    )
```

Функция зависимости `auth` во время выполнения может поднять `HTTPException`, по идее эта ошибка должна быть отловлена в роуте, но

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

=> HTTPException не отлавливается. Почему?

Comment: Не отлавливает потому, что исключение вылетает не внутри вашего try-except, а вообще до входа в handle_create_new_folder